# IOS Swift -Unable to decode all keys from json response

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift and I am trying to parse the json response received from my server. I am unable to correctly decode the server response. Note that I want to change the names of some keys. It is those keys specifically that end up with a nil value.

Here's the actual server response:

```
{
"endpoint":"14.33.21.73:53830",
"dns":"1.1.1.2",
"allowed_ips":"192.168.1.3/32",
"keep_alive":0,
"public_key":"EJueD4OvxWi-EDITED-KNb61hU4akFm1cV65tNcfyGU="
}
```

When I decode the server response

```
if let data = response.body {
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                                
  do {
    let successResponse = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    completion(.success(successResponse))
    return
 } catch { }

}
```

Where T is the following class. Notice that there are some fields I want to rename. For instance the server returns `public_key` which I want to rename to `publicKey`

```
import Foundation

class InterfaceResult: Decodable {
    var endpoint: String?
    var dns: String?
    var allowedIps: String?
    var keepAlive: Int?
    var publicKey: String?
    
    init() {
        
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case endpoint
        case dns
        case allowedIps = "allowed_ips"
        case keepAlive = "keep_alive"
        case publicKey = "public_key"
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        endpoint = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .endpoint)
        dns = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .dns)
        allowedIps = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .allowedIps)
        keepAlive = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .keepAlive)
        publicKey = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .publicKey)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        try container.encodeIfPresent(endpoint, forKey: .endpoint)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(dns, forKey: .dns)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(allowedIps, forKey: .allowedIps)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(keepAlive, forKey: .keepAlive)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(publicKey, forKey: .publicKey)
    }
}
```

When the response from the server is decoded the fields that I ended up renaming i.e. `public_key` to `publicKey` are nil.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can not both set `.convertFromSnakeCase` and use a `CodingKeys` enum since this results in a clash. The decoder will both convert to snake case _and_ look for keys with underscore, like for instance public_key. So remove one of them. Also, can all values really be nil? Only use optional if needed. And you don’t need any custom decoding/encoding code.

Comment: Removing the keyDecodingStrategy resolved my issue. I'm pretty new at swift. Thank you Joakim.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use regular initialiser for JSONDecoder, you don't need to use . convertFromSnakeCase its enough to use enum with CodingKeys protocol.

To decode data in swift using Decodable models you have to follow next steps:

1. Get the endpoint json data
2. Depend on this data create your model
3. Models constants or variables should be the same as keys from your json
   3.1) If you want to use custom keys you can use CodingKeys protocol and designated initialiser required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {}
4. Make sure your generic function gets correct type of your model
5. You don't have to take body from you response, NSURLSession already have in-build method which return data from request